# Не отображается ImageView в телефоне

Tags: android, activity, imageview

Делаю Splash screen. Создал layout `splash_screen.xml`. В нем задал фон и добавил `ImageView`. Использую его в активити `SplashActivity`. Прописал её в `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Но на телефоне `ImageView` не отображается. В чем может быть проблема?

**splash_screen.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dfddfdsfsdfsfs"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**SplashActivity**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        /*
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }*/

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**AdroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ferisov.atlantteam">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: он отображается, только очень быстро.

Comment: @Serodv я ставил sleep он в классе закомментирован, но это не помогло.

Comment: `dfddfdsfsdfsfs` это векторное изображение в xml? Поддержка вектора включена в `build.gradle`?

Comment: @eugeneek как узнать какое оно? Я в paint его рисовал, расширение у него .png . Как проверить включена ли поддержка векторов gradle?

Comment: уберите для начала startActivity() и finish(), если картинка будет отображаться, то сделайте отложенный запуск MainActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изображение не отображается, потому что не успевает отрисоваться. В текущем виде ваш код сразу запускает новую активити и закрывает сплеш.

В варианте с `Thread.sleep()`, вы блокируете UI поток, и из за этого изображение также не может отрисоваться.

И вообще, если вы ничего не собираетесь делать в `SplashActivity`, но хотите сплеш скрин, то он делается по другому.

### Как сделать правильный Splash Screen в Android

Создаётся `background_splash.xml` в `res/drawable` с вашим изображением:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/backgroundColor"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/dfddfdsfsdfsfs"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Затем в `styles.xml` создаётся новая тема с только что созданным бекграундом:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Теперь вам нужно установить данную тему для вашего *главного* активити в манифесте:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

И в конце в коде вашего главного активити вам просто нужно сменить тему на основную:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Переключение на основную тему приложения
        // Обязательно вызывать до super.onCreate
        setTheme(R.style.ThemeApp);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Никаких белых экранов. Никаких лишних активити, которые ничего не делают. Никаких искусственных задержек при старте. [Источник](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd).

Comment: Блестяще! А по поводу `setTheme` - зачем? На других активностях 100% будут другие темы

Comment: @Flippy Мы тут не делаем отдельную `SplashActivity`. Тема ставится у главной активити (будет отображаться вместо белого экрана) и затем `setTheme` меняет тему на основную. Если не менять, то фон у главной активити останется со сплеш бекграундом.